# How to stop repeating the same Javascript functions over and over

Tags: javascript

As I write more and more Javascript I find myself repeating certain variables and functions over and over. For instance in my current project I have already used this piece of code 6 times:

```
var loadDataInto = $('#page');

loadDataInto.empty();
loadDataInto.UIBusy({'color':'#000', 'size': '100px'});
```

However I change the values of loadDataInto and loadDataInto.UIBusy each time I use it. This is just one example where I seem to repeat code and hope its a good enough example.

Is there a way to clean up my code and declare this once, changing the values when I call it? Almost like a SASS mixin? I hope this makes sense!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it a separate function and pass the values as arguments?

Comment: Learn about writing your own functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Comment: …and use a loop maybe?

Comment: Thanks everyone! @Patsy Elementary maybe but you gotta learn some how! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it a function:

```
function dataLoad(id, color, size) {
    var loadDataInto = $('#' + id);

    loadDataInto.empty();
    loadDataInto.UIBusy({'color':color, 'size': size});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend jQuery and use selectors:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.myfunction = function() {
      this.empty();
      this.UIBusy({'color':'#000', 'size': '100px'});
   }; 
})( jQuery );

$('#page').myfunction();
```

with params (as Pointy said):

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.myfunction = function(color, size) {
      this.empty();
      this.UIBusy({'color':color, 'size': size});
   }; 
})( jQuery );

$('#page').myfunction('#000', '100px');
```

Comment: Yes, plus there's no reason not to give the jQuery extension parameters for the color and size.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar to @tymeJV, but pass `styles` instead of separate parameter for color and size:

```
function dataLoad(id, styles) {
    var loadDataInto = $('#' + id);

    loadDataInto.empty();
    loadDataInto.UIBusy(styles);
}
```